# Navigate to a new window on item click in ItemTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemtemplate, icommand

I have created a Grid with ItemTemplate and now on click of any item I want user to navigate to new screen. I have added ICommand function in ViewModel for this but I am not able to handle the Command event in this. Also I am not sure how to display a new window above current one(like Stackview).
Following is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="FingerPrintItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding FingerPrints}"
                  BorderThickness="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:IconButton Command="{Binding SelectFingerPrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource IconButton}" Label="{Binding Name}" Icon="{StaticResource IconDefault}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="2" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    public ICommand SelectFingerPrintCommand => _selectFingerPrintCommand ??= new RelayCommand<object>(OnSelectFingerPrintCommand, CanSelectFingerPrint);

        private bool CanSelectFingerPrint(object param)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void OnSelectFingerPrintCommand(object param)
        {
            if (param == null) { return; }
            var fingerPrint = (FingerPrintViewModel)param;
            
        }

private ObservableCollection<FingerPrintViewModel>? _fingerPrints;
        private ICommand? _selectFingerPrintCommand;
```

I am not even able to get debugger in OnSelectFingerPrintCommand. So it looks there is some problem in my Command also. Can someone please help me?

Comment: In order to bind to the view model, i.e. the DataContext of the ItemsControl, write `Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectFingerPrintCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"`

Comment: Thanks, it works now, will it be possible for you to also help me in opening new window from here? I want to open a new window on click of items in ItemControl and also pass some objects with it.